# Can't find the object while using double curly brackets in the function

Tags: r, dplyr

I was trying to write a function using {{}} to pass variables. Codes are below:

```
diagnostic <- function(data, x, y){
    model <- lm({{y}}~{{x}}, data=data)
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(model)
}
```

And when I wanted to use this function, I typed

```
diagnsoic(mydata, x=exer_past_mvpa, y=visuospatial_constructional_index_score_ch)
```

Both are the existing variable names in my dataset. However, I got this error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
object 'visuospatial_constructional_index_score_ch' not found
```

Would appreciate any advice here! Packages `tidyverse`, `dplyr`, `rlang` were loaded.

Thanks,
May

Answer (score 2):

We may do this in `base R` with `reformulate` and `deparse/substitute`

```
diagnostic <- function(data, x, y){
    y <- deparse(substitute(y))
    x <- deparse(substitute(x))
    fmla <- reformulate(x, response = y)
    model <- lm(fmla, data=data)
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(model)
}
```

-testing

```
diagnostic(mtcars, cyl, mpg)
```

-output

[image]

---

If we want to use `rlang` then an optino is to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
 diagnostic <- function(data, x, y){
      model <- rlang::inject(lm(!! rlang::ensym(y)~!! rlang::ensym(x), data=data))
      par(mfrow=c(2,2))
      plot(model)
  }
diagnostic(mtcars, cyl, mpg)
```